# Insulation inside HVAC duct (and related issues)

Tags: hvac, insulation, pest-control

Should I be concerned with the fiberglass insulation batts the former owners of my home stuffed in an uncapped end of our rectangular HVAC duct?

I noticed this set up when investigating rat/mouse infestation where they've clearly burrowed in the Batts in the ceiling of my unfinished basement.

My solution was to remove the soiled insulation, cap the duct, and put up new batts.

Is that a reasonable solution?  Ultimately I'm concerned about the health risks but building/safety/damage is a close second.  I have consulted a pest control company as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response was fine. The previous owners were probably trying to cap the duct, but didn't realize that fiberglass insulation is air-permeable.